# Explain The Following Attribute Of Integral

Tags: integration

Explain The Following Attribute Of Integral:
$$ \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx  $$
I know that $ \int_a^a f(x)\,dx = 0 $ but how it helps me?
Thanks!

EDIT

Tought about this : 
$$   \int_a^c f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx  = F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c) = F(b)-F(a)  \rightarrow \int_a^b f(x)\,dx $$

Comment: I think you have $a,c$ and $c,b$ reversed on the right hand side.

Comment: The answer to this is really going to depend on the "level" you're studying at. Do you mean Lebesgue integration or Riemann integration? (It's fine to say that you don't know, but give some detail on what you've been taught that integration is.)

Comment: If $$\frac{d g(x)}{dx}=f(x),\int_a^bf(x)dx=g(b)-g(a)$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Wouldn't it be circular to use the FTC?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee $g(a)$ says $ \int_a^a g(x)\,dx$ right?

Comment: $$\int_a^a f(x)dx=g(a)+c-\{g(a)+c\}=0$$

Comment: So how I handling the c there ?

Comment: @Manishearth, why do you think so?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Because most proofs of the FTC involve using this property to split $$\newcommand{\intf}[2]{\int\limits_{#1}^{#2}f(t)dt} \intf{a}{x+h}=\intf{a}{x}+\intf{x}{x+h}$$

Comment: @Manishearth, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Proof_of_the_second_part

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Ah, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the rigorous mathematical proof. Of course, you can easily use the "area under a curve" geometrical definition of a definite integral, but others have given that answer.

---

For this, you need to understand what  [Darboux integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral) are.

A **partition** of $[a,b]$ is a sequence of values $a=x_0<x_1<x+2<.....<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$.

The **upper Darboux sum** on a partition $P$ is $U(F,P)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})\left(\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]} f(x)\right)$

The **lower Darboux sum** on a partition $P$ is $L(F,P)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1})\left(\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_{i}]} f(x)\right)$

The **Upper Darboux integral** is $U(f) = \inf\{U_{f,P} \colon P \text{ is a partition of } [a,b]\}$

The **Lower Darboux integral** is $L(f) = \sup\{U_{f,P} \colon P \text{ is a partition of } [a,b]\}$

A **Darboux integrable** function has $U(f)=L(f)$

With these definitions in mind, we can use the following proof (taken from my typed notes, may be partially similar to the professor's proof):

> Suppose $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and $c\in[a,b]$. Then
>   $$\int\limits_a^b f(t)dt=\int\limits_a^c f(t)dt+\int\limits_c^b
> > f(t)dt$$ First we note that if $c = a$ or $c = b$, there is nothing to
>   prove.
>
> Next, if $c\in (a,b)$ we proceed as follows. If $P_1$ is a partition
>   $[a, c]$ and $P_2$ is a partition of $[c, b]$, then $P_1\cup P_2 = P'$
>   is obviously a partition of $[a, b]$. Thus, partitions of the form
>   $P_1\cup P_2$ constitute a subset of the set of all partitions of $[a,
> > b]$. For such partitions $P'$ we have $$L(f,P')=L(f,P_1)+L(f,P_2)$$.
>   Let us denote by $L(f)_{[a,c]}$ the Darboux lower integral on the
>   subscripted interval.
>
> If we take the supremum over all partitions $P_1$ of $[a,c]$ and
>   $P_2$ of $[c,b]$ we get $$\sup\limits_{P'}
> > L(f,P')=L(f)_{[a,c]}+L(f)_{[c,b]}$$ Now the supremum on the left hand
>   side is taken only over partitions $P'$ having the special form $P_1
> > \cup P_2$. Hence it is less than $\sup\limits_P L(f,P)$ where this
>   supremum is over \red{all} partitions $P$.
>
> We thus obtain $$L(f)_{[a,c]}+L(f)_{[c,b]}\leq L(f)$$. On the other
>   hand, for any partition $P$, we can consider the refinement $P'=P\cup
> > \{c\}$. This can be written as the union of two partitions $P_1$ on
>   $[a,c]$ and $P_2$ on $[c,b]$.
>
> By the property for refinements for Darboux sums we know that
>   $L(f,P)\leq L(f,P')$. Thus, given any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, there
>   is a refinement $P'$ which can be written as the union of two
>   partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$ of $[a,c]$ amd $[c,b]$ respectively, and by
>   the above inequality $$\sup\limits_P L(f,P) \leq \sup\limits_{P'}
> > L(f,P')$$ where the first supremum is over all partitions $P$ and the
>   second is only over the partitions $P'$ which can be written as a
>   union of two partitions as shown above. This shows that $$L(f)\leq
> > L(f)_{[a,c]}+L(f)_{[c,b]}$$ Together with the previous inequality we
>   get $$L(f)= L(f)_{[a,c]}+L(f)_{[c,b]}$$. We can apply a similar
>   reasoning for the upper sums, proving the property.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

What's the definition of *definite* integral? Area under the graph.**Now you know why**.

Comment: Technically not rigorous, but I guess that's OK :)

Comment: @Manishearth: The co-ordinates ain't so perfect. That's how my guide thought me. :)

Comment: Nothing to do with the coordinates. The geometrical proof, while appealing, is not a complete rigorous proof on its own.

Comment: @Manishearth: Rigorous proof? Yeah, it isn't. It attracts large audience though.